# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'archivePath' on task ':jar'

Tags: gradle

I was trying to change a [jar archive output path](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archivePath).

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

jar {
    archivePath = "$destinationDir/../$archiveName"
}
```

Then I get the error: `Cannot set the value of read-only property 'archivePath' on task ':jar'.`

Is there any way already how I can achieve this change?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html). `archivePath` is just a read only property that is constructed from `destinationDir` and `archiveName`. You can modify both of the mentioned properties, but not the result.

Comment: The statement `destinationDir = new File("$destinationDir/..")` changes `$destinationDir`, but the jar file still goes to `lib` folder.

Comment: Have you run `clean` task after changing the script?

Comment: Do you have any example that reproduces the problem?